# `cargo package`: error: main function not found

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to package a library using the `cargo` package manager for Rust. When I try to run `cargo package` per the [documentation](http://doc.crates.io/crates-io.html), I get the following output:

```
error: main function not found
error: aborting due to previous error
failed to verify package tarball
```

I'm confused. I'm trying to package a library (with useful external functions), so I expect that I don't need a `main` function. Here is my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]

name = "package-name"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [ "Kevin Burke <kev@inburke.com>" ]
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   └── main.rs
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah! If you are packaging a library for other programs to use (as I am trying to do), you need to name your file `lib.rs`.

Alternatively, if you are packaging a binary, name your file `main.rs` (this was my mistake).